# LIBGDX / OpenGL : Reducing the size of everything

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, viewport

This could be the worse question ever asked however that would be a cool achievement.

I have created a 3D world made of cubes that are 1x1x1 (think Minecraft), all the maths works great etc.  However 1x1x1 nearly fills the whole screen (viewable area)

Is there a way I can change the ViewPort or something so that 1x1x1 is half the size it currently is?

Code for setting up camera

```
 float aspectRatio = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
 camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, 1.0f * aspectRatio, 1.0f);

 camera.near = 0.1f; // 0.5 //todo find out what this is again
 camera.far = 1000;
 fps = new ControlsController(camera , this, stage);
```

I am using the FirstPersonCameraController and PerspectiveCamera to try and make a first person game

Comment: Use an `OrthographicCamera` if you don't want perspective and set its size to e.g. `2 x 2`.

Comment: If you are needing the PerspectiveCamera, it's as simple as moving the camera farther away from the cubes.

Comment: I am using the First Person Camera and am making a 3D FPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is:

```
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, 1.0f * aspectRatio, 1.0f);
```

An standard initialization of your camera could be (based on [this tutorial](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/)):

```
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
// ...
```

Note how the width and height of the camera is nearly (if not the same) of the width and height of the native gdx window dimension. In your case you set this size to 1 (the same size of your mesh). Try with a bigger viewport dimension to allow your mesh be smaller (in perspective), something like:

```
/** Not too sure since is a perspective view, but play with this values **/
float multiplier = 2; // <- to allow your mesh be a fraction
                      //    of the size of the viewport of the camera
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, multiplier  * aspectRatio, multiplier );
```